# Why is my panel expanding in the MD breakpoint

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing a web app in bootstrap and I have a problem when I put a panel in my page. Everything looks fine on the xs, sm and lg breakpoints but when I resize my screen to the md breakpoint the header breaks out of the flow of the page and fills most of the page.

The html looks normal to me:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion56" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading collapsed" role="tab" id="Product0heading56" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Product0section56" data-parent="#accordion56" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Product0section56">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Test Header
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="Product0section56" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Product0heading56" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created a fiddle here to explain:

https://jsfiddle.net/lukebrowning/9y4yra0k/2/

You will need to resize the example to the md breakpoint (I've put the current visible breakpoint in the blue alert at the top). The header I am talking about is the one 3/4 of the way down the page, is bright blue and with the heading "Test Header".

Any help working this out would be brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem here actually is not with the element containing "Test Header" - in fact, the strange behaviour is caused by the elements above it. These elements each have a class of `.col-md-12` - and at the md breakpoint, any `.col-md-*` elements receive `float: left`.

What you're seeing now is the interaction of floated elements with non-floated content - the non-floated container ignores the floated elements, but inline content flows around them. This is why the blue background of the header's container extends all the way to the top of the fields, while the `<h3>` "Test Header" itself still remains below them, stretching out the container to an enormous height.

My suggestion? Leverage the Bootstrap framework and use the `.row` class in a container around those `.col-md-12` elements. It's what the class is meant for - clearing its children so they don't cause this kind of issue. So your HTML in that section would become:

```
<!-- [...] -->
<div class="row">
    <div id="ctl15" class="bpControl bpResponsive checkboxEdit col-md-12   has-error has-feedback col1">
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- [...] -->
    <div id="ctl55" class="bpControl bpResponsive numberEdit changed col-md-12">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion56" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading collapsed" role="tab" id="Product0heading56" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Product0section56" data-parent="#accordion56" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Product0section56">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Test Header
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="Product0section56" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Product0heading56" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <!-- [...] -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- [...] -->
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9y4yra0k/3/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you - this pointed me in the right direction! It turns out the issue was due to an extra closing div tag that broke the layouts by closing the row it was in and meant I went outside of the row.

Comment: Ack, I must have overlooked that in your code. In any case, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

It must help you

```
div.section .panel-default {
    border-color: #179cd9;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this did fix the issue (in a hacky sort of way), the solution from Serlite actually pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I agree with you, was glad to help ;)